# How do I change default option in magento 2 admin menu?

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to remove the prefix name option for customer on checkout page. I know we can disable it in admin menu but is there anyway I can change the default value of Show in Storefront from yes to no? Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Can you describe your requirement in some more details.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya thanks for response, I wanted to change the " Show on Storefront " default option ( which lays under Storefront Properties in the attached image) from Yes to No. Fortunately I figured it out earlier today and done it with a simple data patch.